# hashCode complexity requirement

Tags: java, hashcode

I am working on the immutable `Board` class, which represents N-by-N board of 15 puzzle game *(in case of N-by-N, it would be N^2 - 1 puzzle game)*. I have overridden `equals()` *(shown below)* and consequently `hashCode()` method in order to preserve the *Object contract*, however hashCode method, **which I want to implement**, takes quadratic time (it should check all N^2 - 1 entries).

So my question is: Is it considered a bad practice if hashCode doesn't take constant time, since it could detriment performance of `HashMap` / `HashTree` (which I am not going to use anyway)? Should I opt for something simpler, such as returning the same prime every time, even though it will increase collision?

Sample 3-by-3 Board (taken from toString() method)

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6 
7  0  8
```

**Two `Boards` are deemed equal iff, all entries match.**

Snippets of code from Board class:

```
public class Board {

    private final int[][] tilesCopy;    // tiles
    private final int N;                // size of the board

... code...


@Override
    public boolean equals(Object y) {
        if (!(y instanceof Board)) return false;
        Board that = (Board) y;
        if (this.size() != that.size()) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.size(); j++) {
                if (this.tileAt(i, j) != that.tileAt(i, j)) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    ...code...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice is to be as fast as possible, from the reasons you have mentioned. But **it is more important for the `hashCode` to be discriminative**.

It is quite obvious that when you have `N*N` elements, the hash should consider them all. 
When you would try to ignore something, it would lead to more collisions, which -- for HashMaps etc leads to more `equals` calls, that would be even more expensive (even though you can quickly `return false` when you find mismatch, the amount of `equals` would be asymptotically bigger than the `hashCode` invocations).

When the `hashCode` is going to be called more times on an instance, and is expensive to compute, you should eveluate it just once, and **cache it** for further calls (of course, your object has to be immutable, or you would have to invalidate the cached hashCode on the object mutation).

---

*Update:* As an inspiration, the Java collections (`Lists`, `Sets` etc.) hash codes calculations include looping through all elements too. Even though it would be OK (from the API contract point of view) to use just the collection's size as a hash code.

*Update 2*: If you are not going to use any *hash* collections, you can actually implement `return 0` hash code, because it won't be used anyway. But you should implement it if you are sharing this implementation with somebody else, as they might want to put it to such collections.

Answer (score 0):

It is not considered "bad practice".  Good or bad practice really doesn't come into it.

What you really need to consider is whether it is the best solution.  Is there a way to calculate a hashcode that isn't `O(N^2)`?  Are you going to be calculating these hashcodes often enough for an `O(N^2)` to be significant *overall*?  Can you avoid (re-)calculating the hashcode for the same state?

Thinking outside of the box a bit, lets assume that your board states are actually related to each other, with one state representing an incremental change (a move) from the previous state.  (That is how game rules normally work ...) If you chose the hashing algorithm appropriately, you could exploit the incremental nature of the game to calculate the hash code of a new state from the hashcode of the previous state.

For example, the XOR function has the property that it is reversible; i.e. if A XOR B is C, then C XOR B is A.  So if the hashcode of a board state is composed of the XOR of the hash of the elements, you can go from `hashcode(state S)` to `hashcode(state S + 1)` by XORing in just the hashcodes for the state elements that have changed.

Of course, you need to be caching the hashcodes in the objects that represent the board states.  But if you do that you should be able to calculate a hashcode in `O(1)` rather than `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Why would one cache the hashcode when the calculation itself is in `O(1)`?

Comment: Because the approach I advocate is only O(1) if calculating the hashcode of the previous state is `O(1)`, and that only happens if the previous state's hashcode is cached.  Without caching, the calculation would be `O(N^2)` and we would have gained nothing.